# Detect text from image via Webcam

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ocr

I have a warehouse and for inventory purposes I need to scan new items. Some of them do not have any barcodes, so I thought of scanning their labels with a webcam and compare the name with the name from the database.

Therefor I would need some kind of combination of Javascript/JQuery and PHP.
I thought of capturing the image via Javascript and then post it to PHP. In PHP I thought of using an OCR Software like Tesseract OCR to detect the items name on the label. If I get so far the rest will be a piece of cake.

Is my plan possible ?
If so does anybody already have some experience with that or could recommend some software I could use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem now and want to provide my solution in case someone is looking for something similar.

I created a `<video>` on my webpage displaying my webcam with HTML and Javascript using the `.getUserMedia()` function. I then created a pseudo canvas and got the data URI out of it.

The picture was posted in base64 to [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2015-q2-cloud-emea-gcp-bkws-freetrial-en&gclid=CjwKEAjwsr-6BRCLvrj785rbhTsSJADjUxakDms0i4Br9hm6babamU11G5yKbyo1HmTKq03gTKRBjxoCR57w_wcB)'s OCR (text detection). This returned the results of the scanned image very accurate.

Comment: Anybody knows anything cheaper than GCV?

Comment: I found [Tesserect.js](https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/) promising in this kind of scenario.